# Angular route not working in custom menu directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am having hard time to route to particular url since the menu is coming from directive. Below is the code:

The Route:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'mainMenu']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/main.html'    
            })
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/home.html'    
            })
            .when('/bollywoodGossips', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/bollywoodGossip.html'    
            })
            .when('/bollywoodNews', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/bollywoodNews.html'    
            })
            .when('/bollywoodEvents', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/bollywoodEvents.html'    
            })
            .when('/bollywoodFitness', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/bollywoodFitness.html'    
            })
            .when('/bollywoodWallpaper', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/bollywoodWallpaper.html'    
            })
            .otherwise('/', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/main.html'    
            })
    })
```

The Directive:

```
(function(){

    var mainMenu = angular.module('mainMenu', []);

    var newMenu = function($location) {

        var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.parent('a.menuBtn').click(function(){
                element.toggleClass('test');
            });


        }

        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          replace: true,
          templateUrl: 'pages/directiveTemplate/menu.html',    
          link: link    
        }
    }

    newMenu.$inject = ['$location'];

    mainMenu.directive('newMenu', newMenu);

}());
```

The Menu Template:

```
<ul class="dropdownMenu">
    <li><a href="#/bollywoodGossips">Bollywood Gossip</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/bollywoodNews">Bollywood News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/bollywoodEvents">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/bollywoodFitness">Celeb fitness Mantra</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/bollywoodWallpaper">Celeb Wallpapers</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the html:

```
<div class="mainMenu">
        <p>
            <a href="#/home"><span class="breadCrumb">Home</span></a>
            <a href="" class="menuBtn">Menu&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span>
                <new-menu></new-menu>
            </a>
        </p>           
    </div>
```

The Index file:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="mainHeader">
                        <img src="imgs/mainHeader.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-view></div>            


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="footer">
                        <p>&copy;2016 All rights reserved. NAYSA VAS Communications Pvt.Ltd.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
```

This renders correctly but when i click on any link inside the menu it does not route to that particular url. e.g #/bollywoodGossips .should go to index.html#/bollywoodGossips but it is not routing and remains still on index.html#/home. Please help I am new to directives..

Comment: Your IIFE is wrong. Use `})();` not `}());`.

Comment: but it doesn't solved my problem

Comment: @cst1992 both examples are valid IIFE. The one he uses is actually the one Douglas Crockford advises to use, although I prefer the one you wrote

Comment: @Sam Are you sure the $location is getting injected into the function newMenu? $inject is written above the function body, not in isolation like this.